# How can I read App Configuration Store endpoint and environment from local config store in azure functions?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-app-configuration

I am moving our configuration from our local configuration store to a central App Configuration Store for all our Azure Functions.

I have created a startup.cs and the code looks as follows

```
public override void ConfigureAppConfiguration(IFunctionsConfigurationBuilder builder)
        {
            if (builder == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(builder));

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            var credentials = GetDefaultAzureCredential();

            builder.ConfigurationBuilder
                .AddAzureAppConfiguration((options) =>
                {
                    options
                        .Connect(
                            new Uri(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ConfigurationStorePrimaryEndpoint")),
                            credentials
                        )
                        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, LabelFilter.Null)
                        .Select(KeyFilter.Any, "DEVELOPMENT");
                });

        }
```

I cannot figure out how to read the variables ConfigurationStorePrimaryEndpoint and DEVELOPMENT from the local Configuration on the function itself? I do not want to use env variables I want to read those two values from the local configuration store on each function but I cannot figure out how?

And of course when run locally I want it to use the local.settings.json

Any suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SomeConfigurationSetting")` would load value of "SomeConfigurationSetting" key from `local.settings.json` when you run locally. When you deploy in Azure, just add the same entry in [app settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#settings) of the Function app. It does not have to be "Environment variable" literally like in OS level. Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?#environment-variables) for details.

If you don't want this way and you meant some custom "local configuration store", then you need to share details on that.

Answer (score 0):

Store the output of `builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();` and use to access the configuration from local configuration file.

```
var configuration = builder.ConfigurationBuilder.AddEnvironmentVariables().Build();

... Some  code

options
  .Connect(
      new Uri(configuration["ConfigurationStorePrimaryEndpoint"]),
      credentials
   )

 ... Some  code
```